# Magnitude based colored points in Octave or MATLAB or in any other software

Tags: matlab, plot, octave

I have *Z* = *f(x,y)*. I have discrete values of *Z*. I want to get a 2-D plot where the magnitude of *Z* is represented by the color of the points. The color should vary gradually as the magnitude of *Z*.

I prefer a Octave or MATLAB solution, but any other software is fine. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

One possible way is to use [imagesc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imagesc.html):

Example:

```
Z = rand(10);
imagesc(Z)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `surf()` along with `view` in MATLAB. Try this:

```
figure;
surf(Z);
view(2); % top-down view
```

You can also enable a color chart that shows color-value correspondence via the [`colorbar`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colorbar.html) command.

Comment: This gives a 3-D plot. I want a 2-D plot.

Comment: Not if you use the `view` property.

Comment: Yeah. Working. But can I have discrete points plotted instead of a smooth surface?

Comment: If I understand what you mean, try `surf(Z, 'EdgeColor', 'None')` instead of `surf(Z)`. Rafael's solution will work as well.

Comment: Like _scatter_ function. I want to see individual points. Not a smooth continuous surface.

Answer (score 0):

Create a meshgrid with x and y as arrays:

```
[X,Y]=meshgrid(x,y)
```

Then use surf to get discrete colored plot with the z values controlling the intensities.

```
surf(X,Y,z)
```